# Slowdown when loading the same SpriteFrame used in an animation in Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am currently experiencing some heavy slowdowns with my game. I have narrowed it down to something related with texture animations.

In my game there are characters that walk in 1 of 4 possible directions, they will walk up to a point, then change direction and continue walking (sort of like a tower defense game).

First i am loading the sprite frame cache like this

```
SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("characters.plist");
```

This code is only run once during the life time of my application.

When the characters get loaded to the screen their animation is being set using the following code:

```
int direction = 0;
int number = 0;

if (this->to_x < 0) // Left
{
    direction = 1;
    number = 1;
}
else if(this->to_x > 0) // Right
{
    direction = 2;
    number = 1;
}

if (this->to_y < 0) // Down
{
    direction = 0;
    number = 0;
}
else if(this->to_y > 0) // Up
{   
    direction = 3;
    number = 2;
}

int s = 0; //skin


// Set the animation
Animation *animation = Animation::create();

for (int i = 0; i < INT16_MAX; i++)
{
    string frame_sprite_name = StringUtils::format("%s_%d_%d_%d.png",parameters[name].image_name.c_str(),s,number,i);

    auto frame = SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->getSpriteFrameByName(frame_sprite_name);

    if (frame) {
        animation->addSpriteFrame(frame);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

// Invert the sprite when they go right
if (direction == 2) {
    setFlippedX(true);
}else{
    setFlippedX(false);
}

// Set the pace of the animation based on the type
if (name=="runner") {
    animation->setDelayPerUnit(0.15f);
} else{
    animation->setDelayPerUnit(0.3f);
}

Animate *animate = Animate::create(animation);
this->stopAllActions();
this->runAction(RepeatForever::create(animate));
```

What this code does is:

1. Check the direction
2. Get the sprite frame from the cache based on the direction
3. Run the action with repeat forever.

However this code is ran every time they change direction to set the new animation of the active characters. Also, at one time I can have around 40-50 of these characters going around.

I've noticed that after a few minutes in the game the slowdown starts to happen as soon as a new "character" is created, (since they are created in rapid succession in waves). And the slowdown also happens when the characters change in direction. So this makes me believe I am using the textures wrong.

If anyone knows how to fix this please let me know.

PD: I was thinking about the possibility of pre-loading all the animations and then just having each of the sprites that represent the characters run the corresponding animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely cache the animation in the AnimationCache with `addAnimation` and `getAnimation` methods.

Comment: Following your advice, im using the animation cache now and the performance has improved greatly. I'm still wondering why is the performance so bad when using SpriteFrameCache since its kind of supposed to do the same thing for sprite frames...

Comment: Well SpriteFrameCache improves loading time or usage of sprite frames loaded from a TexturePacker PLIST or other means. It is not supposed to improve performance of creating an animation every frame or every .1 seconds.

Comment: You can also instead try running animations by getting a sprite frame from the cache and then setting the sprite's frame on each update or every .1, for example. Essentially what Animate action does internally.